# typescript code style TS2539:Cannot assign to 'execFile' because it is not a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, intellij-idea

I have a code

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as globby from 'globby';
import { execFile } from 'child_process';
import * as util from 'util';
//import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
import * as fs from 'fs';

execFile = util.promisify(execFile);
```

when it compiler to js

show error log like this

```
Error:(12, 1) TS2539:Cannot assign to 'execFile' because it is not a variable.
```

what should i rewrite code for fix this in right way, or just keep ingorne it

Comment: Import bindings are immutable, you shouldn't be trying to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up `types` for your tsconfig in `compilerOptions`, like this

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [ "es2015"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
```