# error TS2539: Cannot assign to 'c' because it is not a variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 .ts files,

C.ts:

```
export let c: any = 10;
```

A.ts:

```
import { c } from "./C";
c = 100;
```

When I compile A.ts, a error:

```
error TS2539: Cannot assign to 'c' because it is not a variable.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect `c` is a `let` so it's scoped to the imported file?

Comment: Hope this helps - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6751

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704189/typescript-code-style-ts2539cannot-assign-to-execfile-because-it-is-not-a-var

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See, there's a confusion here. And Dr. Axel Rauschmayer nailed it in [this article](http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html):

> CommonJS modules export values. ES6 modules export bindings - live
>   connections to values.

```
//------ lib.js ------
export let mutableValue = 3;
export function incMutableValue() {
    mutableValue++;
}

//------ main1.js ------
import { mutableValue, incMutableValue } from './lib';

// The imported value is live
console.log(mutableValue); // 3
incMutableValue();
console.log(mutableValue); // 4

// The imported value can’t be changed
mutableValue++; // TypeError
```

---

So you have two options:

- adjust the compilerOptions so that your module is treated as CommonJS one
- treat the imported values as bindings (aliases), not true identifiers

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And if my understanding is correct, when they are **bindings**, `c = 100` is supposed to "rebind identifier `c` to object `100`" but `c` is not an actual identifier.

Answer (score 33):

place it inside a class, and make it static

```
export class GlobalVars {
  public static c: any = 10;
}
```

after importing it from any other file

```
GlobalVars.c = 100;
```

Comment: This seems like a more elegant solution than the accepted answer

Comment: Awesome answer! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use objects as namespaces:

```js
export let state = {
    c : 10 as number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could of course just export as an object with the `c` variable inside, for example:

```
export const options = {
    c: 10 as number
}
```

Answer (score -9):

can't assign c variable because you use let

```
export let c: any = 10;
```

you have to give like

```
export c: any = 10;
```